# How to fit a 3D surface to geographic coordinates?

Tags: matlab, matrix, surface

Good day everyone;

I have a **M*N** matrix and I have two coordinate vectors **X** and **Y**, where **X** has the length of **M** and **Y** has the length of **N** but they have different values because **M** is an array index and **X** is a Latitude coordinate, for example 
`M=linespace(0,1000,1000)` and `X=linespace(-31.291666,51.958332,1000)` and similar case for **N** and **Y**.

I want to know if there is a way to plot the same data in `M * N` in a figure surface figure with axis **X*Y** in matlab?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
[a,b] = meshgrid(x,y);
% z is your 100x1000 matrix
mesh(a,b,z);
```

Comment: That did the trick, I knew it had to be something simple.
Thanks Steffen! Have a great day!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please be sure to mark this answer as correct.